# If $|(-n,n)\cap A|+|(-n,n)\setminus A|=2n$ then there exist Borel sets $F_n\subset A\cap (-n,n)\subset G_n$ such that $|G_n\setminus F_n|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

"If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then there exist $F_n\subset A\cap [-n,n])\subset G_n$ such that $|G_n\setminus F_n|=0$"

**EDIT: As Andreas Blass and BigbearZzz note in the comments below the statement is false unless one assumes the additional hypothesis that** $|(-n,n)\cap A|+|(-n,n)\setminus A|=|(-n,n)|$ for all $n\geq 1$ - **see also the edit below**

---

<s>that is presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870116/232754) and the first part, about the existence of a measurable set $G_n$ such that $E\cap [-n,n])\subset G_n$ is clear, and we can easily state something stronger: if $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ then there exist a measurable set $O$ such that $A\subset O$ and $|A|=|O|$ and the proof is pretty straightforward.</s>

The problem is that I haven't been able to understand how one can come up with a measurable set $F_n\subset E\cap [-n,n]$ such that $|G_n\setminus F_n|=0$: the proof in the link seems to apply the fact that we proved above to the complement of $E\cap [-n,n]$ but after that I get lost so I would be grateful if someone could show me an easier proof or restate the one I have linked in a more easily understandable way, thanks.

---

**EDIT** This is the version of the proof presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870116/232754) that I also referenced before, which I have restated in a way I can understand better - comments are welcome:

"Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be such that $|(-n,n)\cap A|+|(-n,n)\setminus A|=2n$ for all $n\geq 1$: then, for every $n\geq 1$ there exist Borel sets $F_n, G_n$ such that $F_n\subset (-n,n)\cap A\subset G_n$ and $|G_n\setminus F_n|=0$".

*Proof.* Fix $n\geq 1$. By the [measurable cover lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4248698/232754) we can find a Borel set $G_n\supset (-n,n)\cap A$ such that $|G|=|(-n,n)\cap A|$ and also a Borel set $H_n\supset (-n,n)\setminus A$ such that $|H_n|=|(-n,n)\setminus A|$. As $H_n\supset (-n,n)\setminus A$ it is $(-n,n)\setminus H_n\subset A$ so if we set $F_n:=(-n,n)\setminus H_n$ we have that $F_n\subset A$ and $F_n$ is Borel so
$|(-n,n)\cap F_n|+|(-n,n)\setminus F_n|=|(-n,n)|$ which implies $$\fbox{$|(-n,n)\cap F_n|$}=|(-n,n)|-|(-n,n)\setminus F_n|= |(-n,n)|-|H_n|=|(-n,n)|-|(-n,n)\setminus A|\overset{hypothesis}{=}\fbox{$|(-n,n)\cap A|$}$$ hence $|G_n\setminus F_n|=|G_n|-|F_n|=|(-n,n)\cap A|-|(-n,n)\cap A|=0$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: (1) The statement in the title is false unless $E$ is measurable. (2) Your $O=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty O_n$ is not in general open.

Comment: @lorenzo My proof in the link you provided doesn't apply to an arbitrary $E$ but $E$ such that $m^*(E)+m^*([-n,n]\backslash E)=m^*([-n,n])$. This condition is equivalent to Lebesgue measurability.

Comment: @BigbearZzz thank you for your help: I have edited my question according to your comment and I think it is correct now.